# Are two halves of PBKDF output "related"

Tags: key-derivation

In other words, in the context of authenticated encryption using Encrypt-Then-MAC, is this stupid?:

```
derived_key = PBKDF(key, salt, dkLen=32)
hmac_key, enc_key = derived_key[:16], derived_key[16:]
```

It is advised that separate keys be used for MAC and encryption. Is this sufficient? If not, how dangerous is it?

Comment: A standard model for PBKDFs is for their output to be indistinguishable from a truly random string so this should be fine.

Comment: Avoid `dkLen` >  `hLen` for PBKDF2 when doing password stretching. Its method of deriving more than `hLen` bytes is less efficient than it should be. Since whatever hash used likely has at least 256-bit output (32 bytes), this is not an issue. Argon2, a way better password-based KDF for Intel/AMD hardware, doesn't have such an issue.